# Hardware sizing for Hyperledger Fabric network/application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric and exploring it everyday.
Have few queries regarding the transaction size, block size and ideal hardware sizing for the application deployed on the fabric network:

1) As per my understanding, transactions are stored in JSON format (in CouchDB), so assume if my data size per transaction is ~5kb, what will be the additional data (hash,header,signature etc) size I can expect?

2) On what basis blocks get generated in fabric. I have gone through [config.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/13447bf5ead693f07285ce63a1903c5d0d25f096/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go) file and have referred **BatchSize** parameter but if my txn size is very less (say ~5kb) then does that mean that no block will get generated until it reaches **PreferredMaxBytes** or **MaxMessageCount** ?

3) What should be the ideal configuration (CPU,RAM,HDD) of the peer machines/orderer w.r.t Production env. (assuming 5tps , 4 Org network)?